# Java - Selenium > I want to make the instance one time per page class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, instance

In order to avoid duplicating my code and not inserting these code lines in every test, I would like to know if there is an effective/efficient way that I'll use only one time in the class/page. I want to initialize the objects at just one time. Thanks for your assistance!

Here is my code:

```
public class ContributionTests extends BaseTest {
    @Test (priority = 1)
    @Severity(SeverityLevel.CRITICAL)
    @Description("Create a Contribution E2E, using only required fields, and validate the new creation contribution name")
    public void tc1_CreateContribution() throws InterruptedException {
        MainPage mainPageGP = new MainPage(driver);
        AssetTabPage assetTabPage = new AssetTabPage(driver);
        UnderManagementAssetPage umap = new UnderManagementAssetPage(driver);
        ContributionTabPage ctp = new ContributionTabPage(driver);
        NewContributionFormPage ncp = new NewContributionFormPage(driver);
        NewCreatedContributionPage nccp = new NewCreatedContributionPage(driver);
        ExistingContributionPage ecp = new ExistingContributionPage(driver);

        mainPageGP.setMainTab("Assets");
        assetTabPage.selectUnderManagementTab();
        getSleep(500);
        assetTabPage.selectAsset("new Asset- Test on Edge");
        getSleep(500);
        umap.selectInnerTab("Contributions");
}
```

I didn't try anything yet but expect to spare a lot of code lines in my test classes.

At this time, I insert these initializers in every test:

```
        MainPage mainPageGP = new MainPage(driver);
        AssetTabPage assetTabPage = new AssetTabPage(driver);
        UnderManagementAssetPage umap = new UnderManagementAssetPage(driver);
        ContributionTabPage ctp = new ContributionTabPage(driver);
        NewContributionFormPage ncp = new NewContributionFormPage(driver);
        NewCreatedContributionPage nccp = new NewCreatedContributionPage(driver);
        ExistingContributionPage ecp = new ExistingContributionPage(driver);
```

This is my "setup" method that I extend from the `BaseTest` class:

```
    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("remote-allow-origins=*");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        PropertyUtils u = new PropertyUtils();
        driver.get(u.readProperty("url"));
        LoginPage lp = new LoginPage(driver);
        lp.loginToPage();
    }
```

Comment: and what is your actual question? Have you tried using an initializer method with the Before annotation?

Comment: My actual question is how do I spare these code lines and use the initialize only one time in the test class file? I don't want to write these code lines in every test I create. seems that it is a redundant duplication. I hope I wrote the question in the best simple way... :)

Comment: so ... again: did you try using an initializer method with the Before annotation?

Comment: Not sure I really know what you mean.
I can provide more info about my setup method in my baseTest file...

Comment: so, you want to go selenium testing without knowing the basics of tests? what part of my suggestion didn't you understand?

Comment: Well, I mean what you wrote "initializer method"( not sure if you mean to Java method). BTW- 
1. I'm doing my first steps in selenium testing 
2. I know the "Before" annotation. I used this already
3. Note that I edit again my main question and I provide more info...

Comment: using a method that initializes your tests (annotated with Before) is an initializer method. Since you 've already used that, how don't you see that that is the answer to your question?

Comment: Never mind. SORRY. I thought you mean other "Before" annotations (like BeforeTest e.g.) I didn't know this annotation before. I'm still In the learning process